# Which sorting algorithm is best suited to re-sort an almost fully sorted list?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a list of strings which has been sorted by a specific comparison function.

Now I have to re-sort this list using a *different* comparison function.

This new comparison function behaves slightly different when comparing certain special characters, like Umlauts for example. In most cases the element has to be moved just one or two slots to get to the correct position.

Which sorting algorithm is best suited to re-sort this almost fully sorted list in terms of runtime execution speed?

Comment: Are you really looking for an *algorithm* or just a heuristic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which sort algorithm works best on mostly sorted data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220044/which-sort-algorithm-works-best-on-mostly-sorted-data)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) works well on small or nearly sorted lists.

From this [ACM Paper](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=359024.359026):

> Tests on randomly generated lists of
>   various combinations of list length
>   and small sortedness ratios indicate
>   that Straight Insertion Sort is best
>   for small or very nearly sorted lists
>   and that Quickersort is best
>   otherwise.

From wiki article [Insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort):

> If the input array is already sorted,
>   insertion sort performs as few as n-1
>   comparisons, thus making insertion
>   sort more efficient when given sorted
>   or "nearly-sorted" arrays.

SO Question: [Is there ever a good reason to use Insertion Sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736920/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-use-insertion-sort)

Comment: Note that QuickerSort is not QuickSort, but there is a close resemblance; in modern terminology, QuickerSort might be deemed a variant of QuickSort which always sorts the shorter subset first (minimizing stack depth for recursion) and which has a simple partition selection criterion that is probably susceptible to bad worst case performance, but which would work well for the almost-sorted case under discussion here.

Comment: @Max: not really (@Henk and I had this discusion a short time ago). BubbleSort is usualy used for no reason other the developer remembers it from college and it's simple (but not much simpler than insertion sort), and it seems like a general purpose sort and is fast when they test with a small number of randomly ordered items. Insertion Sort is being choosen in a specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Have access to both search operations? If yes, you can to build some hash tree during first sorting process and use it to other sort operations

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your data list is allready sorted (let say by ascii/country charset order), but without some dictionary rules applied for particular country. For example Germany and their Umlauts

see Germanic_umlaut in wikipedia

you are not inserting new items, you just want to resort them by little bit more strict sorting rule.

as you can read for example here

http://www.softpanorama.org/Algorithms/Sorting/bubblesort.shtml

bubble sort works well on allready sorted lists with just a few permutations. This sounds like bubble sort is good algorithm to start with. Also note that bubble sort is "stable" sorting algorithm. This could be important for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

For nearly sorted lists, variations of the [Comb](http://sites.google.com/site/computersciencesourcecode/sortroutines) sort outperform the Quicksort.  I haven't tested to see how the comb sort compares to the Insertion sort.