# What kind of tree is used in Java's TreeSet and TreeMap?

Tags: java, collections, tree

Are they AVL trees, red-black trees, or something else?

Comment: It's the second and third words in the JavaDocs.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*Red-black* trees as described in the first line of the javadoc.

- [Tree Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)
- [Tree Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

Answer (score 23):

From the [`java.util.TreeMap<K,V>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) documentation:

> A [Red-Black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) based [`NavigableMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) implementation.

For questions like these, you should always first consult the documentation. The API shouldn't describe *ALL* of the inner-workings of a `class`, but elementary informations such as general data structures and algorithms used are usually documented.

---

#### Other Java Collections Framework trivias

These are all little trivias that are also clearly documented:

- [`TreeSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is implemented with a `TreeMap`
- [`HashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) is implemented with a `HashMap`
- [`Collections.sort`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) uses modified mergesort
- [`Map<K,V>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is not a `Collection<?>`
- [`ArrayList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) doesn't specify exact growth policy (unlike, say, `Vector`)

#### Related questions

- [Why does `java.util.Arrays.sort(Object[])` use 2 kinds of sorting algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566843/why-does-java-util-arrays-sortobject-use-2-kinds-of-sorting-algorithms/)
- [Why does the Java Collections Framework offer two different ways to sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892947/why-does-the-java-collections-framework-offer-two-different-ways-to-sort)
- [Why doesn't Java Map extends Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651819/why-doesnt-java-map-extends-collection)

Answer (score 5):

The first sentence of [the TreeMap Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) states:

> A Red-Black tree based `NavigableMap` implementation.

Answer (score 5):

It is a red-black tree in the Oracle desktop Java implementation, but an [AVL-tree in Android](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/util/TreeMap.java).

Answer (score -5):

TreeSet is based on TreeMap.
And they uses red-black tree,  **red-black tree is a kind of AVL**.

Comment: Red-black trees and AVL trees are two different things.