# sort algorithms for mostly sorted list

Tags: algorithm, list, sorting

I am working on a list of integers from a file. And I have to use a sorting algorithm to categorize them in descending order. I am familiar with the run time of a few sorting algorithms and I know the use of them is situational. So my question is: **What would be the quickest sorting algorithm for a list of ANY size that is already 90% sorted?** (in my file I have 10.000 entries but 9.500 of them are already sorted).

Thank you,

Comment: As a start, why don't you benchmark some? Insertion sort works well for small nearly sorted lists..but is it the fastest?

Comment: my personal any case favorite is an introsort algorythm, if you know there is a pretty high percent of almost sorted lists, you can just set up the heapsort walk in.

Comment: Depending on the platform, the default sort may already be adaptive. For example, Python and Java 7 use [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), which is a mergesort that takes advantage of runs already present in the input. Check if you can just use an appropriate library function.

Comment: Insertion Sort seems to be popular for this type of input.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513566/which-sorting-algorithm-is-best-suited-to-re-sort-an-almost-fully-sorted-list

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220044/which-sort-algorithm-works-best-on-mostly-sorted-data

Comment: @Zaibis But doesn't heapsort require the use of nodes?

Comment: Sorting really isn't that situational, except for pre-existing data structures.  Lacking those, a good median Quicksort is usually the fastest except for the most marginal situations.

Comment: I just tried using a bubble and a selection sort. Both have the same runtime, but it seems like the Insertion sort is what everyone suggests. I'll just go with that. Thanks for the replies y'all.

Comment: What do you mean with nodes ? and I'm not talking about heapsort at all, im talking about introspective sort (its an mixture of quicksort and an sort algo of O(n log n) (as heapsort for example is one.

Comment: And are you lookig for an sort algo to use or to write it by ur self?

Comment: Have you consulted [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms) et al?

Comment: @Samuel: Heapsort does not require nodes. You can implement a heap in an array, no nodes required.

Comment: If the 9,500 items are already sorted and you just need to add 500 unsorted, probably the quickest will be to sort the 500 (using your library supplied sort) and then merge with the 9,500. Honestly, though, sorting 10,000 items only takes a few milliseconds. Unless you're doing this thousands of times per second, you're much better off using whatever your language library supplies.

Comment: a good link to see your self which sorting algorithm is best: which in my opinion is insert sorting. Go to link: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insertion sort should be fine, if you choose to code it yourself rather than using the language provided sort functions.

1. It performs really well when the list is almost sorted (Though it
   is of Order O(N^2), if the list is almost sorted, the inner loop
   will not be executed often)
2. It is pretty easy to implement.

Presenting the Python implementation of Insertion Sort.

**Program**

```
def InsertionSort(Array):
    Total = 0
    for i in xrange(1, len(Array)):
        j, I, = i - 1, i
        while j >= 0 and Array[I] > Array[j]:
            Array[I], Array[j] = Array[j], Array[I]
            j, I, Total = j - 1, I - 1, Total + 1
    print "Insertion Sort Total Operations :", Total
```

**Output**

**Worstcase**

```
TestArray  = range(1, 11)
InsertionSort(TestArray)
Insertion Sort Total Operations : 45
```

**Bestcase**

```
TestArray  = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
InsertionSort(TestArray)
Insertion Sort Total Operations : 0
```

**90% Sorted Array**

```
TestArray  = [1, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 10]
InsertionSort(TestArray)
Insertion Sort Total Operations : 17
```

**Half Sorted Array**

```
TestArray  = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
InsertionSort(TestArray)
Insertion Sort Total Operations : 10
```

Comment: But, of course, the above Python code given should only serve as pseudo code to aid in implementing insertion sort in other languages. In Python use the built-in sort which uses Timsort, which is even better for partially sorted data.

Answer (score 5):

The [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) algorithm as developed for Python, (and now used in Java), has optimisations to deal with partially sorted "runs" built in.

Comment: Timsort in C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556935/fast-clean-c-timsort-implementation . And Timsort in Java: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~martin/webrevs/openjdk7/timsort/raw_files/new/src/share/classes/java/util/TimSort.java

Comment: The following post on Timsort in C# has statistics comparing Timsort to C#'s native modified Quicksort routine for random and partially sorted data as well as the C# code for Timsort: http://timsort4net.codeplex.com/

Comment: I recently benchmarked the C# Timsort implementation from http://timsort4net.codeplex.com/ and was surprised to find it about 3x slower than .NET 4.0's default Array.Sort() call for all array sizes > 64. This held even over varying degrees of array disorder from about 10% random to 100% random. Both .NET and Timsort times reduced with less initial disorder, but the ratio remained about 1:3 in all cases. There may be one or more serious implementation faults with this code.

Comment: It turns out I was actually benchmarking against the .NET 4.5 introspective sort, which is an improvement over earlier implementations. So my benchmarks showed the .NET 4.5 introspective sort to be about 3x faster than the timsort4net.codeplex.com implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For its std::sort C++ uses introspective sort, where the array/list is first sorted using **quicksort** for a certain depth of recursion followed by **heapsort**. I dunno about 90% but heapsort seems to perform well on already sorted arrays/lists... so I'd recommend you try that.