# what is threshold in merge sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort, insertion-sort

i can not understand threshold in merge sort and how can I determine it.
i google it but no result. can anyone explain it for me?
i want to sort the array[50000] using merge sort, when threshold crossover using insertion sort.

```
private int[] MergeSort(int[] lst)
    {
        int hl = lst.Length - 0;

        if (hl < 5 || hl < 10 || hl < 15 || hl < 20 || hl < 25 || hl < 30 || hl < 35 || hl < 40 || hl < 45 || hl < 50)
        {
            RunTime run = new RunTime();
            run.X = hl;
            InsertionSort(lst);
            run.Ttime = Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime.Milliseconds;

                _listRunTime.Add(run);



        }

        if (lst.Length == 1)
            return lst;
        int middle = lst.Length / 2;
        int[] left = new int[middle];
        for (int i = 0; i < middle; i++)
        {
            left[i] = lst[i];
        }
        int[] right = new int[lst.Length - middle];
        for (int i = 0; i < lst.Length - middle; i++)
        {
            right[i] = lst[i + middle];
        }
        left = MergeSort(left);
        right = MergeSort(right);

        int leftptr = 0;
        int rightptr = 0;

        int[] sorted = new int[lst.Length];
        for (int k = 0; k < lst.Length; k++)
        {
            if (rightptr == right.Length || ((leftptr < left.Length) && (left[leftptr] <= right[rightptr])))
            {
                sorted[k] = left[leftptr];
                leftptr++;
            }
            else if (leftptr == left.Length || ((rightptr < right.Length) && (right[rightptr] <= left[leftptr])))
            {
                sorted[k] = right[rightptr];
                rightptr++;
            }
        }
        return sorted;
    }

    private void InsertionSort(int[] arr)
    {
        int i, j, tmp;
        for (i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            j = i;
            while (j > 0 && arr[j - 1] > arr[j])
            {
                tmp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
                arr[j - 1] = tmp;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
```

i must use threshold instead of `if (hl < 5 || hl < 10 || hl < 15 || hl < 20 || hl < 25 || hl < 30 || hl < 35 || hl < 40 || hl < 45 || hl < 50)` .

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question that discusses this topic: [Why should Insertion Sort be used after threshold crossover in Merge Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622015/why-should-insertion-sort-be-used-after-threshold-crossover-in-merge-sort)

basically, a threshold is just a number n such that if there are n elements unsorted left after running merge sort, we switch to insertion sort.  n is pretty ambiguous I believe and you can test it out on your code to see which n optimizes performance.  So no, there is no way to determine the threshold number unless you try out a bunch of different values and test the performance.

btw isn't your huge if statement the exact same as

```
if(hl < 50)
```

?