# selection algorithm for median

Tags: algorithm, brute-force, median-of-medians

I was trying to understand the selection algorithm for finding the median. I have pasted the psuedo code below.

```
SELECT(A[1 .. n], k):
if n<=25
use brute force
else
m = ceiling(n/5)
for i=1 to m
B[i]=SELECT(A[5i-4 .. 5i], 3)
mom=SELECT(B[1 ..m], floor(m/2))
r = PARTITION(A[1 .. n],mom)
if k < r
return SELECT(A[1 .. r-1], k)
else if k > r
return SELECT(A[r +1 .. n], k-r)
else
return mom
```

i have a very trivial doubt. I was wondering what the author means by brute force written above for i<=25. Is it that he will compare elements one by one with every other element and see if its the kth largest or something else.

Comment: It probably means that he will just sort and pick the middle value. Maybe post the site where you got this

Comment: Yes. The brute force will use an algorithm similar to selection sort to find the middle value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code must come from [here](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs473/notes/01-recursion.pdf).

A brute force algorithm can be any simple and stupid algorithm. In your example, you can sort the 25 elements and find the middle one. This is simple and stupid compared to the selection algorithm since sorting takes `O(nlgn)` while selection takes only linear time.

A brute force algorithm is often good enough when `n` is small. Besides, it is easier to implement. Read more about brute force [here](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~black/cs350/Lectures/lec05-Brute%20Force.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Common wisdom is that Quicksort is slower than insertion sort for small inputs.   Therefore many implementations switch to insertion sort at some threshold.

There is a reference to this practice in [the Wikipedia page on Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).
[Here's an example](http://penguin.ewu.edu/cscd320/Topic/ArraySort/MergeSort/Arrays_sort.html) of commercial mergesort code that switches to insertion sort for small inputs.  Here the threshold is 7.

The "brute force" almost certainly refers to the fact that the code here is using the same practice: insertion sort followed by picking the middle element(s) for the median.

However I've found in practice that the common wisdom is not generally true.  When I've run benchmarks, the switch has either very little positive effect or negative.  That was for Quicksort.  In the Parition algorithm, it's more likely ot be negative because one side of the partition is thrown away at each step, so there is less time spent on small inputs.  This is verified in @Dennis's response to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101546/why-is-insertion-sort-better-than-quick-sort-for-small-list-of-elements).