# Quick Sort vs Insertion Sort

Tags: sorting

When building a sorting algorithm to sort an array, how many n elements in the array is quick sort faster that Insertion sort? I know that Quick sort is good for   more elements and that Insertion sort is great for smaller size. But was wondering around what size is Quick Sort a far better option than Insertion Sort?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Insertion sort better than Quick sort for small list of elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101546/why-is-insertion-sort-better-than-quick-sort-for-small-list-of-elements)

Answer (score 0):

These algorithms depend on more than just the size of the arrays to determine their run time. For quicksort, the pivot your algorithm selects can have a significant effect on runtime. If the pivot is consistently the greatest or least element, then the quicksort takes `O(n^2)`. Insertion sort is also influenced by factors besides array size. If you are inserting elements in order, the algorithm might allow for a runtime of `O(n)` regardless of array size. However, if you are inserting in reverse-order, this algorithm will take `O(n^2)`. Due to these factors, there is no size n for which one algorithm is guaranteed to perform better than the other. If you are concerned with the runtimes of sorting algorithms for large arrays, you should check out heapsort or mergesort, they are both `O(n log n)` and are much faster!